# Scala/SBT: "object is not a member of package", but the object is in external libraries

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, playframework, sbt, akka

In a Scala 2.13.4/SBT 1.2.8 project, the class `MyService.scala` has this import:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport
```

I think the library that contains this class, is added by `sbt` as a dependency of one of the libraries that I added as `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`.

However when I compile the project, I get:

```
$ sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/java-8 -jvm-debug 9999 run
...
[info] Compiling 31 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/me/projects/my_project/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[error] /home/me/projects/my_project/app/actors/MyService.scala:8:8: object AkkaGuiceSupport is not a member of package play.api.libs.concurrent
[error] import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport
[error]        ^
```

In IntelliJ, in the project's External Libraries, I can see:

[image]

**What am I missing here?**

**What could be the reason for this compilation error?**

........................................................

**Update:**

**build.sbt**

```
name := "CH07"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `ch07` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cacheApi,
  ws,
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play28" % "0.11.0",
  "org.hsqldb" % "hsqldb" % "2.5.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.14.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.29",
  "com.github.scullxbones" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-common" % "3.0.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence" % "2.6.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-query" % "2.6.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-typed" % "2.6.10"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7")
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=1.3.10
```

Comment: It has been a while that I dont use play framework. But I guess you are missing the `anorm` and `ehcache` libs and why do you use the `ch07` instead of `lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)` as it is mentioned here -> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/BuildOverview

Comment: @Felipe Regardless of the libraries being used. If you see that a class is on the classpath, what could make it not being seen by the compiler?

Comment: I agree with you. But maybe there is some dependency that we dont know since Play uses akka underneath and versions could vary. I was just thinking that is worthwhile to test....

Comment: @Felipe I should mention that in Intellij, the Play plugin (in project/plugins.sbt), and akka-persistence and play-memcached dependencies that are added in build.sbt — are marked as "Unknown artifact. Not resolved or indexed." However, most of the akka and play classes that are imported in the project, are resolved by the compiler (both by sbt on the command line, and in intellij). Weird.

Comment: Rapt, does my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can see it because it is part of the play framework. You can see in [`PlayImport`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.0/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L14) more packages that you did not import but they are there because of play. For example, if you remove [`jdbc`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.0/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L35) from `libraryDependencies`, you will probably see more such errors (just with a different package name, and only in case you are actually using it). Note that you will be able to find the missing classes in the IntelliJ tree, while the compiler won't.

The missing import in your case is [`guice`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.0/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L73). [`AkkaGuiceSupport`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.0/core/play-guice/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/concurrent/AkkaGuiceSupport.scala#L47) is part of `guice`. Try to add it into your library dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice, // This is the missing part
  jdbc,
  cacheApi,
  ws,
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play28" % "0.11.0",
  "org.hsqldb" % "hsqldb" % "2.5.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.14.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.29",
  "com.github.scullxbones" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-common" % "3.0.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence" % "2.6.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-query" % "2.6.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-typed" % "2.6.10"
)
```